# Set second datefield value to after 7 days from first selected datefield value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I need to set the second date field value to after 7 days from first date field value. this should happen when I select the first date field. here's my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function pageLoad() {

         $("[id$=txtToDate]").datepicker({
             'format': 'yyyy-mm-dd', autoclose: true, todayHighlight: true
         }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
         $("[id$=txtFromDate]").datepicker({
             'format': 'yyyy-mm-dd', autoclose: true, todayHighlight: true
         }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
     };

     </script>
    ////
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-10">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">From Date :</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">To Date :</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                             </div>
                          </div>


    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Are you want to set second datepicker's start date 7 days ahead from first datepicker? If that's what you want, sounds like this should be apply when changing first datepicker: `$('[id$=txtToDate]').datepicker('setStartDate', e.date.getDate() + 7);`

Comment: Yes thats what i wanted. i'm new to these things and can you please let me know what is the event that i should call this?

Comment: your pageLoad() not run?

Comment: no it's running. should I add this java script code to pageload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture value using `$("[id$=txtFromDate]").datepicker("getDate")` with `change` event from first datepicker and set `minDate` option of second datepicker with updated date value. Below is an example to accomplish your task:

```
$("[id$=txtFromDate]").datepicker({
   'format': 'yyyy-mm-dd', 
   autoclose: true, 
   todayHighlight: true,
}).attr('readonly', 'readonly').change(function() {
    var date2 = new Date($("[id$=txtFromDate]").datepicker("getDate"));
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 7); // set 7 days ahead
    $('[id$=txtToDate]').datepicker("setDate", date2); // set date value of second datepicker
    $('[id$=txtToDate]').datepicker("option", "minDate", date2); // set minimum date of second datepicker
});
```

**Note:** You can do the reverse way for `txtToDate` with `date2.setDate(date2.getDate() - 7);` and `txtFromDate` as target, so that both datepicker may adjust themselves.

**Additional note:** If you're experiencing issue with datepicker selectors and not using `ClientIDMode="Static"`, replace `$("[id$=datepickerid]")` to `$('<%= datepickerid.ClientID %>')` like given example below:

```
$("<%= txtFromDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({
   'format': 'yyyy-mm-dd', 
   autoclose: true, 
   todayHighlight: true,
}).attr('readonly', 'readonly').change(function() {
    var date2 = new Date($("<%= txtFromDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("getDate"));
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 7); // set 7 days ahead
    $('<%= txtToDate.ClientID %>').datepicker("setDate", date2); // set date value of second datepicker
    $('<%= txtToDate.ClientID %>').datepicker("option", "minDate", date2); // set minimum date of second datepicker
});
```

Working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/190484/)

Comment: Are you getting errors in browser console, or the datepicker is not functioning properly? Possibly you need like `<%= txtToDate.ClientID %>` as selector if the ClientIDMode is not set to `Static`.